# Version 9.0 refuses to display uparrow U+2191 in AxesLabel/FrameLabel

Tags: plotting

Odd bug, but all other arrows except U+2191 work in AxesLabel/FrameLabel. The arrow displays properly elsewhere, but in plot there is a blank character space. It occurs regardless of whether the label is rotated or not, or of use of frames, or if subscripted. Is there a way troubleshoot this and get it working? Thank you for your help!

```
ListLinePlot[{DOS0U,DOS1U,DOS2U},PlotRange->{{-2,2}, 
{0,0.9}},RotateLabel->False,PlotLegends->Placed[{"h=0","h=1","h=2"}, 
{0.85,0.8}],Frame->True,FrameStyle->Directive[Black,15],FrameLabel-> 
{Style["\[Omega]",FontSize->20,FontColor-   
>Black],Style["Subscript[\[Rho], \[UpArrow]]",FontSize- 
>35,FontColor->Black]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `Subscript["\[Rho]", "\[UpArrow]"]`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but have tried that and the wysiwyg. No dice. However, I found a dirty workaround by exporting to image with downarrow, then rotated the arrow 180 in gimp. I'll be upgrading soon and will see if the problem persists, but was curious to see if it's just my install or if anyone else has the problem too... and it's annoying.

Comment: It was a shot into the dark anyway. Btw., you can also do the rotation trick also within Mathematica, e.g. with `Rotate["\[DownArrow]", Pi]`. (You said that `\[DownArrow` would worked, right?)

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know that was a possibility, and it worked! Now that is weird, but makes sense since it's a rotated downarrow. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!